# Dojo datagrid filtering by "ANY COLUMN" broken by IE's max URL length limit

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, datagrid, dojo

Internet Explorer cannot handle URLs longer than 2083 characters (ref: [What is the maximum length of a URL in different browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers))

Using a Dojo EnhancedGrid with the Filter plugin, it is possible for a user to apply a filter to "ANY COLUMN". With serverside filtering enabled, the resulting URL is the same as if the user applied the same filter individually to every column, producing a GET request to a very long URL.

Is there a way around this?

```
var myStore = new JsonRest({target:"duck/", sortParam: "sortBy"});
grid = new EnhancedGrid({
    store: dataStore = new ObjectStore({objectStore: myStore}),
    id: "colId",
    query: { colId: "*"},
    structure: [
    //whole bunch of columns
    ],
    plugins:{
        filter:{
            isServerSide: true,
            itemsName: "ducks",
            setupFilterQuery: function(commands, request){
                request.query.filter =  JSON.stringify(commands.filter)
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two options I see are:

1) Modify or switch the objectstore to be able to POST the filter parameters.

2) (chosen) Compress the URL using a simple search/replace dictionary. This works very well if you target large chunks of frequently recurring JSON.